# How do I save link in .txt file?

Tags: python, selenium, append, txt

```py
try:
    links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="s-item__wrapper clearfix"]//a[@class="s-item__link"]')
    for link in links:
        print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

I want to save all links file in txt file

Comment: please edit your question i can not understand what you're saying

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('links.txt', 'w') as file:
    try:
        links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="s-item__wrapper clearfix"]//a[@class="s-item__link"]')
        file.write('\n'.join(links))
```

Use `open()` to open files for read or write. More info [here](https://realpython.com/read-write-files-python/).